# Calculate if day/night time for point dataset

Tags: pyqgis, vector, spatio-temporal-data

I have a point dataset (crime data for Stockholm) with timestamps and I want to calculate for each point if the certain crime happened during day or night time. So connecting the timestamp to sunrise and sunset. I know that there is a python tool called pyephem, but I don't know how I can use this tool to automatically calculate day/night time for my entire dataset.

So I would need a python code, which imports the timestamp column for each feature. In the next step it has to be calculated if it is day/night for every point and finally a new column should be added in shapefile with the calculated result (e.g. 'day' / 'night').

Comment: `pyephem` is a python package, you install it in your system then python code can do `import ephem` and then use its methods to get sunrise/sunset times. For your second paragraph perhaps the easiest thing to do is to write a new custom python expression and then you can use that in the expression evaluator on the attribute table viewer.

Comment: but as it sits this question is asking too many things, and you should try and break it down into simple chunks, have an attempt to do them yourself, and then come back with a more focused question when you get stuck. At present it reads like you want someone to write your code for you.

Answer (score 5):

## Part One - using `pyephem`

To answer part one of your question, you can use `pyephem` to compute the altitude angle of the Sun at any given location and time. For example the following function:

```
import ephem
def sunup(lat, long, time):
   o = ephem.Observer()
   o.long = long
   o.lat = lat
   o.date = time
   s = ephem.Sun()
   s.compute(o)
   return s.alt > 0
```

creates an "Observer" at a given place and time and then computes the position of the Sun so that its `alt` attribute is the number of degrees above or below the horizon. The last line defines daytime as when the sun is above the horizon, but you could use this altitude angle to define daytime, nighttime, and twilight.

So for my approximate location, today:

```
>>> sunup("53", "-2", '2018/02/08 16:30:00')
True
>>> sunup("53", "-2", '2018/02/08 17:30:00')
False
```

which tells me that the sun set between 16:30 and 17:30 in **UTC**, not local time (but I'm in the UK so its coincidentally the same).

Note the lat-long values are characters and if you pass numbers bad things happen:

```
>>> me = ephem.Observer()
>>> me.lat = "53.33333333333"
>>> me.lat
53:20:00.0
>>> me.lat = 53.33333333333
>>> me.lat
3055:46:29.7
```

So that's part one, how to use `pyephem`. Part two depends on how you are storing dates and times and how much python and python-qgis you know or want to learn - best asked as a new question.

## Part 2 - QGIS integration

Here's the connection between that code and QGIS. Open the attribute editor, and use the field calculator to create a new custom function. Include the above code that works out the sun altitude, and add this:

```
@qgsfunction(args='auto', group='Custom', usesgeometry=True)
def daytime(datefield, feature, parent):
    date = str(feature.attribute(datefield))
    xy = feature.geometry().asPoint()
    return ["Night","Day"][sunup(str(xy[1]),str(xy[0]),date)]
```

Then in the field calculator you can run `daytime('datefieldname')` and use that to update or create a column based on the datestamp in a field called `datefieldname`, but this has to be in the right format for `pyephem`.

Once the function is defined you can even run it from the speedy bar at the top of the attribute table - here it is updating column `test2` from the locations of the features and the date stored in the `date` column:

[image]

Note this only works if your point data is in lat-long EPSG:4326 projection unless you want to write the conversion code into the function too...